# Login window hangs upon user login

Tags: macos, performance, user-account

When I want to fast user switch from user A to user B, a **login window** appears where I enter user B's password. When I'm done, a rotating progress indicator spins for a couple seconds, until user B gets logged in.

However, sometimes (as in precisely now), user B is not logged in. The login window is still up and its rotating indicator is still rotating. It has been stuck like that for several minutes. Behind it, *darkened but still visible*, are all user A's windows with their (unsaved) data.

For example: iTunes is still playing, but I can't do anything: the login window cannot be dismissed, and the attempted, and apparently still going on, user login cannot be cancelled.

Command-option escaped to bring up the **force quit window** doesn't do anything.

Trying to share the Mac's screen from another or trying to control it from Remote Desktop doesn't work as the Mac doesn't respond.

However, I can still remote connect with the terminal using SSH. So I still have some hope to recover from the terminal, perhaps by killing the stuck login process.

How can I find out which process to quit? Is there anything else I can try, short of forcing a shutdown of the stuck Mac?

My Mac is running Mac OS X 10.9.2. (No external disk that might be stuck mounting or unmounting.)

Comment: Open Console and look at the time stamp of the event to see what is going on.

Comment: I could not see any relevant information in the Console.

Comment: Forcibly shutting the machine down is safer than SSHing into the machine and killing the hanging process (loginwindow)